# How to add object in an array of objects using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the below JS object and I need to push another similar object with `request.rules[0]`.

```
request :  [
  rules: 
  [
    {
      pageFilters: 
      [
        {
          matchType: 'contains', 
          type: 1, 
          value: 'a'
        }, 
        {
          matchType: 'does not contain', 
          type: 1, 
          value: 'b'
        }
      ], 
      name: 'TEST'
    }
  ]
]
```

This is the object that I need to push to request.rules[1]:

```
{
  pageFilters: 
  [
    {
      matchType: 'contains', 
      type: 1, 
      value: 'c'
    }, 
    {
      matchType: 'does not contain', 
      type: 1, 
      value: 'd'
    }
  ], 
  name: 'TEST 2'
}
```

This is what I've tried to implement, but it does not work ...

```
request.rules[1].pageFilters[0].push({
  matchType: 'contains', 
  type: 1, 
  value: 'c'
})
request.rules[1].pageFilters[1].push({
  matchType: 'contains', 
  type: 1, 
  value: 'd'
})
request.rules[1].name = "TEST 2";
```

This is the expected result:

```
request :[
  rules: 
  [
    {
      pageFilters: 
      [
        {
          matchType: 'contains', 
          type: 1, 
          value: 'a'
        }, 
        {
          matchType: 'does not contain', 
          type: 1, 
          value: 'b'
        }
      ], 
      name: 'TEST'
    },
    {
      pageFilters: 
      [
        {
          matchType: 'contains', 
          type: 1, 
          value: 'c'
        }, 
        {
          matchType: 'does not contain', 
          type: 1, 
          value: 'd'
        }
      ], 
      name: 'TEST 2'
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Is request an array ?

Comment: Just create a new object and then do `request.rules.push(newObj)`

Comment: request.rules seems to have only one element, no?

Comment: `request.rules[0].pageFilters.push({...})`

Comment: Do you get an errors in the console?

Comment: @Maxx I already tried that and it returns me: TypeError: Cannot read property "pageFilters" from undefined

Comment: @Weedoze yes, it's an array

Comment: @Sergeon initially it has only one element, I need to dynamically update it when needed

Comment: `request[0].rules.unshift(youNewObject);`

Comment: What is your expected result? How is `request` going to look like after all?

Comment: @Tresdin I updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: Then you just need to `push` the expected object into `request[0].rules` like this `request[0].rules.push({
      pageFilters: 
      [
        {
          matchType: 'contains', 
          type: 1, 
          value: 'c'
        }, 
        {
          matchType: 'does not contain', 
          type: 1, 
          value: 'd'
        }
      ], 
      name: 'TEST 2'
    });`

Comment: Thank you! I just didn't know that I can do `request.rules.push({ pageFilters: [ { .. } ] })`. You can add your comment as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to push to a specific position e.g request.rules[1].pageFilters[0], but rather to the array itself like this

```
var anotherFilter = {
  matchType=contains, 
  type=1, 
  value=c
};

request.rules[1].pageFilters.push(anotherFilter);
```

Comment: I already tried that and it returns me: `TypeError: Cannot read property "pageFilters" from undefined`

Answer (score 0):

With a proper object with request as object,

```
request: { // should be an object, not an array
    rules: [
```

you could just use

```js
var object1 = { request: { rules: [{ pageFilters: [{ matchType: 'contains', type: 1, value: 'a' }, { matchType: 'does not contain', type: 1, value: 'b' }], name: 'TEST' }] } },
    object2 = { pageFilters: [{ matchType: 'contains', type: 1, value: 'c' }, { matchType: 'does not contain', type: 1, value: 'd' }], name: 'TEST 2' };
            
object1.request.rules.push(object2);
    
console.log(object1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Sorry! My code is formatted by the Google Script console, I will edit it.

Answer (score -2):

I understand you code，
    {
      matchType=contains, 
      type=1, 
      value=c
    }
I seen 
 {
      type:1, 
      value:c
    }